# How to handle pseudo events in UI5 custom controls?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I want to perform some action in my SAPUI5 control when <kbd>Page Up</kbd> / <kbd>Page Down</kbd> is pressed.

How can we handle [UI5 pseudo events](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/module:sap/ui/events/PseudoEvents.events#properties) such as `sappageup` and `sappagedown` in custom control development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your control definition, try with:

```js
metadata: {
  // ...
},

init: function() {
  // ...
},

onsappageup: function() {
  // Page up key pressed!
},

onsappagedown: function() {
  // Page down key pressed!
},
```

From the [API reference of `sap/ui/events/PseudoEvents.events`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/module:sap/ui/events/PseudoEvents.events):

> [...] SAPUI5 controls and elements should simply implement an `onpseudo-event(oEvent)` method. It will be invoked only when that specific pseudo event has been recognized. This simplifies event dispatching even further.

Be aware that such pseudo events can be **only fired if the control has received the focus first**. To make the control focusable, provide the HTML attribute `tabindex`<sup>[[video]](https://youtu.be/Pe0Ce1WtnUM)</sup> to your control. E.g.:

```js
renderer: {
  apiVersion: 2, // or higher. Refer to API reference of sap.ui.core.RenderManager
  render: (renderManager, myControl) => renderManager
    .openStart("div", myControl)
    .attr("tabindex", /*e.g.:*/"-1") // make it focusable
    // ...
    .openEnd()
    // ...
    .close("div")
  },
},
```

---

In case you're working on keyboard handling to navigate items, take a look at the delegate `sap.ui.core.delegate.ItemNavigation`.

- [API reference: `sap.ui.core.delegate.ItemNavigation`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.delegate.ItemNavigation)
- Documentation topic ["Supporting Keyboard Handling in List-like Controls"](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/91f203236f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070)